# MMC cannot save the console

Tags: mmc

I'm local administrator on Windows Server 2012 R2

I need to add a snap-in to MMC.

After I add any snap-in and want to save console I've got error message:

MMC cannot save the console.

How could I fix it?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you verify if you are in "Author mode"? Go to File -> Options and check the "Console mode" option.

Comment: What are your permissions for the destination where you want to save to? Please respond by clicking on `edit` above and to the left to put that important information in the original question.

Comment: I verified that I am in 'Author mode'.
I am local administrator and trying to save MMC to Desktop

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm in the exact same situation

Comment: Hi, No I never resolved it

Answer (score 0):

For one possible solution to this error in Windows 11, [see my complete answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1829575/how-to-disable-the-action-pane-in-mmc/1829576#1829576).

In brief: open the MMC file in a text editor and change `ActionsPaneVisible` from `"true"` to `"false"`. Save and re-run the console.

TIP: For editing text, [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) is a great tool because it colorizes the XML hierarchy.