# How to disable the action pane in MMC?

Tags: windows, mmc

I created a custom console in MMC and saved it. The action pane is shown by default, so I turned it off to get more viewing space (`View > Customize... > uncheck Action Pane`). When I tried to save it again in the same folder, I got this error:

> MMC cannot save the console

It's not a permissions problem and the console is in Author mode. How can I save it without the Action Pane?

NOTE: Linking [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1360024/mmc-cannot-save-the-console) because it's the same error message though for that user the error may have been caused by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, the solution is easy to implement. MMC files are in XML format and can be modified in a text editor. [Notepad++ is free](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) and colorizes the XML as shown:
[image: ActionPaneVisible]

Change `ActionsPaneVisible` to `"false"` and save. Tested on Windows 11 though likely works on other versions.